# How to extract group list element using pandas criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, series

I have a pandas dataframe like as shown below

```
ID,color
1, Yellow
1, Red
1, Green
2, Red
2, np.nan
3, Green
3, Red
3, Green
4, Yellow
4, Red
5, Green
5, np.nan
6, Red
7, Red

fd = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
```

As you can see in the input dataframe, some ID's have multiple colors associated to them.

So, whenever there is multiple color associated to them, I would like to select only one color based on the below criteria

```
['Green','Red','Yellow'] = Choose 'Green'
['Red', 'Yellow'] = Choose 'Yellow'
['Green', 'Yellow'] = Choose 'Green'
```

Basically, **Green is given 1st preference. 2nd preference is for Yellow and last preference is for Red.**

So, if an ID whenever has Green, choose Green (don't care about other colors).

If an ID whenever has Yellow and Red, choose Yellow

If an ID for its all rows has only `NA`, leave it as `NA`

I tried the below but this only gets me the list of color

```
fd.groupby('ID',as_index=False)['color'].aggregate(lambda x: list(x))
fd[final_color] = [if i[0] =='Green' for i in fd[col]]
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

**update**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the values of dataframe on color with the help of the preference dictionary, then drop the duplicates on `ID`

```
d = {'Green': 1, 'Yellow': 2, 'Red': 3}
df.sort_values('color', key=lambda c: c.map(d)).drop_duplicates('ID')
```

Alternative approach by first converting the `color` column to *ordered categorical type*, then groupby and aggregate to select the min value

```
df['color'] = pd.Categorical(df['color'], ['Green', 'Yellow', 'Red'], True)
df.groupby('ID', as_index=False)['color'].agg('min')
```

---

```
   ID   color
0   1   Green
1   2     Red
2   3   Green
3   4  Yellow
4   5   Green
5   6     Red
6   7     Red
```

Comment: thanks, upvoted. Is there anyway to do this without sort? Or this problem will always require sort? because of its nature? Let's say if I want to select a specific color from the list (without any criteria), can just show me how can it be done? You can also retain this sort example as is.

Comment: Let's assume I want to select 'green' color based ID=1,3 and Yellow color for ID=6,7. Can show me how can it be done?

Comment: @TheGreat In that case what would be the color selection for id 2, 4, 5?

Comment: This is slightly different requirement (unrelated to this question). I will create a new post and link it here

Comment: Here is the related post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71544776/how-to-subset-a-dataframe-based-on-multiple-values-of-groupby-list

Comment: by any chance, do you know why do I get all `NA` when I do categorical ordering? updated the screenshoot above in post

Comment: @TheGreat This is due to extra spaces in the color column in the  input dataframe. Use `fd = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',', skipinitialspace=True)` while reading.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is to implement a custom sorting:

```py
sort_preference = {
    'Green': 0,
    'Yellow': 1,
}

(
    fd
    .sort_values(by=['color'], key=lambda x: x.map(sort_preference))
    .groupby('ID')
    .head(1)
)
```

Comment: thanks, upvoted. is there anyway tp do this without sort?

Comment: The answer by @Shubham Sharma, has a version without sort. This is achieved by assigning ordered categoricals.

Answer (score 1):

Without sorting, you can use `idxmin` if you map your color with numeric values:

```
d = {'Green': 1, 'Yellow': 2, 'Red': 3}
out = df.loc[df.assign(num=df['color'].map(d)).groupby('ID')['num'].idxmin()]
print(out)

# Output
    ID   color
2    1   Green
3    2     Red
5    3   Green
8    4  Yellow
10   5   Green
12   6     Red
13   7     Red
```