# How to subset a dataframe based on multiple values of groupby list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, series

I have a dataframe like as below

```
ID,color
1, Yellow
1, Red
1, Green
2, Red
2, np.nan
3, Green
3, Red
3, Green
4, Yellow
4, Red
5, Green
5, np.nan
6, Red
7, Red
8, Green
8, Yellow

fd = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')
fd = fd.groupby('ID',as_index=False)['color'].aggregate(lambda x: list(x))
```

As you can see in the input dataframe, some ID's have multiple colors associated to them.

Now, I would like to create a subset of dataframe with ID's that have both `Yellow` and `Green`

So, I tried the below and got the list of colors for each ID

```
fd.groupby('ID',as_index=False)['color'].aggregate(lambda x: list(x))
```

I would like to check for values like `Yellow` and `Green` in the groupby list  and then subset the dataframe

I expect my output to be like as shown below (only two IDs have Yellow and Green together)

```
ID
1
1
8
8
```

**update**

input dataframe looks like below

[image]

Comment: I wish to subset this dataframe via groupby list (instead of direct subsetting using filter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the rows having color as Yellow or Green, then group the dataframe on `ID` and transform color with `nunique` to check the `ID` having 2 unique color.

```
s = df[df['color'].isin(['Yellow', 'Green'])]
s.loc[s.groupby('ID')['color'].transform('nunique').eq(2), 'ID']
```

Result

```
0     1
2     1
14    8
15    8
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

---

Update as per the new requirements, here I'm assuming `df1` is the input dataframe obtained after `groupby`:

```
s = pd.DataFrame([*df1['color']])
df1[s.mask(~s.isin(['Yellow', 'Green'])).nunique(1).eq(2)]
```

Result:

```
   ID                 color
0   1  [Yellow, Red, Green]
7   8       [Green, Yellow]
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this via groupby list?

Comment: I would like to check for a presence of an element in a list and then select the ID

Comment: upvoted for your help as always

Comment: Not sure if I understand, but are you looking for: `df[df['color'].isin(['Yellow', 'Green'])].groupby('ID')['color'].agg(list)`

Comment: nO. May be you can consider my input dataframe to be as something that you see after the groupby statement that I have written in the post. In that case, we need to check for a presence of an element in the list and then select the ID

Answer (score 1):

From your input dataframe, you can use:

```
colors = ['Yellow', 'Green']
out = df[df['color'].apply(lambda x: set(x).issuperset(colors))]
print(out)

# Output
   ID                 color
0   1  [Yellow, Red, Green]
7   8       [Green, Yellow]
```